# CSS first-letter pseudo element works on chrome, but not on firefox

Tags: css, firefox

Title says it all. Chrome does exactly what I want it to do, but Firefox does not apply any of the style rules to the first letter that I specified. Here's the code, and the section of interest is copied below.

```css
article::first-letter {
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: #990000;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
```

http://codepen.io/patrickfbray/pen/QNdoJq

Comment: still doesn't work with `p`

Comment: Seems you may have updated your Codepen which now works in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `article` doesn't have a `first-letter` to start with...the paragraph within it does though. I'm surprised the original worked in any browser.

```
  <article>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis viverra enim maximus ipsum sagittis, non accumsan sapien porttitor. Nullam neque magna, laoreet et egestas id, sagittis ac magna. Vestibulum eu cursus sapien. Maecenas vel dapibus magna.
    </p>
```

To correct, I'd suggest:

```css
article p:first-letter {
    color: #990000;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 20pt;
}
```

Comment: thanks! everything's working now, i'll keep my common sense with me next time.